# Make every possible permutation of words using only a single list

Tags: java, python, string, algorithm, permutation

I don't really know too much about coding yet (working on it) and this is my first time using this site but not exactly my first time using one like this (So go easy on me lol) and I figured that this would be the best place to ask. So something I'm trying to accomplish right now is trying to make every permutation possible with a single set of words in every possible length without repeating the same word in one result. I couldn't find anything exactly like that since most that I've seen people make or want, have some sort of limit where they only make sets with a specific amount of words in each one instead of all possible lengths, for example, if there's five words, I want the results to have all possible amount of words per set, meaning I want there to be sets with one, two, three, four, and five words, and of course every possible permutation with those sets.

As an example, with every number being the amount of words per set (which it should automatically find so that it'll do every length) it should start out with one word per set and end with five words per set without ever repeating the same word in a single set:

1

```
Alpha
Beta
Charlie
Delta
```

2

```
Alpha Beta
Alpha Charlie
Alpha Delta
Beta Alpha
Beta Charlie
Beta Delta
Charlie Alpha
Charlie Beta
Charlie Delta
Delta Alpha
Delta Beta
Delta Charlie
```

3

```
Alpha Beta Charlie
Alpha Beta Delta
Alpha Charlie Beta
Alpha Charlie Delta
Alpha Delta Beta
Alpha Delta Charlie
Beta Alpha Charlie
Beta Alpha Delta
Beta Charlie Alpha
Beta Charlie Delta
Beta Delta Alpha
Beta Delta Charlie
etc.
.
.
.
```

4

```
Alpha Beta Charlie Delta
Alpha Beta Delta Charlie
Alpha Charlie Beta Delta
Alpha Charlie Delta Beta
Alpha Delta Beta Charlie
Alpha Delta Charlie Beta
Beta Alpha Charlie Delta
Beta Alpha Delta Charlie
Beta Charlie Alpha Delta
Beta Charlie Delta Alpha
Beta Delta Alpha Charlie
Beta Delta Charlie Alpha
etc.
.
.
.
```

Also I don't wanna make this anymore too ridiculous, but would there be a way that I could filter through all the lines just made lines and only pull ones that have a specific occurrence in them? As an example, only pull the lines that have Alpha in them, so that way if I have:

```
Alpha Beta
Alpha Charlie
Alpha Delta
Beta Alpha
Beta Charlie
Beta Delta
Charlie Alpha
Charlie Beta
Charlie Delta
Delta Alpha
Delta Beta
Delta Charlie
```

I can just specifically grab:

```
Alpha Beta
Alpha Charlie
Alpha Delta
Beta Alpha
Charlie Alpha
Delta Alpha
```

So yeah, that's basically what I'm trying to accomplish here, and from what I've seen no one has done this yet or at least never asked for it, and I hope this isn't asking too much here. Thank you in advance for any sort of help that you can give, and especially thank you if you can give me a code or link to one that can do all that.

Comment: Hello, do you have any code that you have started on at all?

Comment: The only thing that I really found that kinda does something close is this:

Comment: var tree = function(leafs) {
  var branches = [];
  if (leafs.length == 1) return leafs;
  for (var k in leafs) {
    var leaf = leafs[k];
    tree(leafs.join('').replace(leaf, '').split('')).concat("").map(function(subtree) {
      branches.push([leaf].concat(subtree));
    });
  }
  return branches;
};
console.log(tree("abc".split('')).map(function(str) {
  return str.join('')
}))

Comment: But it only affects a single word

Comment: I am not a Java programmer (yet), I can give you a Python example in a bit

Comment: Hey I'm willing to take anything I can get lol, so thank you if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, `itertools.permutations` returns fixed length permutations of a collection of things like a list of names. Its easy to write your own generator to run `permutations` for each length you want.

```
import itertools

words = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta"]

def combos(collection):
    """Return all permutations of a collection from length 1 to 
    total length of the collection.
    """
    for r in range(1, len(collection) + 1):
        yield from itertools.permutations(collection, r)

for row in combos(words):
    print(" ".join(row))
```

This produces (with gaps)

```
Alpha
Beta
...
Alpha Beta
Alpha Charlie
...
Alpha Beta Charlie
Alpha Beta Delta
…
Alpha Beta Charlie Delta
Alpha Beta Delta Charlie
...
```